# binding parameters with SQL update query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, parameters, prepared-statement

how can I bind the following parameters in my query? does the "?" count as the parameters and are parameters are positioned in order?

Here's my code:

```
case 'setpassword':  
if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('phone_number','password'))){  
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];  
$password = SHA1($_POST['password']);
 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE phone_number= ? ");  
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$password,$phone_number);  
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();  
   if($stmt->num_rows > 0){  
   $stmt->bind_result($id,$phone_number,$password);  
   $stmt->fetch();  
   $user = array(  

   'phone_number'=>$phone_number,
   'password'=>$password  

   );   

   $response['error'] = false;   
   $response['message'] = 'Password set successful';   
   $response['user'] = $user;   
   }  
   else{  
   $response['error'] = true;   
   $response['message'] = 'Password set error';  
   }  
}  
break;
```

my code has no errors but it cannot find any data.

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5/sha1 for password hashing. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: Have you read through [the manual about prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)? It's pretty extensive.

Comment: `$stmt` is an UPDATE, you run the update and then you try and retrieve the information as though it's a SELECT.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have read this and I still got no idea on the question marks on the statements

Comment: @NigelRen ohh....I did not notice that....thanks!

Comment: _"how can I bind the following parameters in my query?"_ - You're already doing it correctly. _"does the "?" count as the parameters and are parameters are positioned in order?"_ - The `?` is called a "positional placeholder" and refers to the bound parameters. You need to bind the parameters in the same order their placeholders appear in the query.

Comment: Here's an article with a more step by step explanation of prepared statements: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php

Comment: What is your intention?  Only to update the password or  di you want to do something else?